# Azure Logic Apps Problem with Liquid Transformation of SOAP XML

Tags: xml-parsing, liquid, azure-logic-apps

I'm using Azure Logic Apps to integrate with a legacy SOAP API.  I would like to translate the XML (particularly the responses) in to something easier to use such as json.

Normally I use a Custom Connector within Logic Apps to connect to new APIs.  I've tried to create a Custom Connector for this SOAP, but the WSDL contains recursive references which apparently aren't allowed.  I was able to create managed API with our APIM container, but still could not produce anything that would allow me to create the custom connector.  So, I moved on to dealing with the transactions individually.  A Liquid transformation map from XML to json seems ideal, but so far I haven't got it to work, namely because I can't figure out the naming convention to access certain XML elements (those that happen to have the same id as their parent).  For now I am using the json(xml()) function as a work around, but it seems less ideal than a Liquid map.

As you can see the AgreementId is easily accessible via the normal naming conventions, but I can't seem to access any of the child elements of the 2nd RequestReportResponse node.

This is the XML I'm trying to transform:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
   <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <RequestReportResponse>
         <MessageHeader>
            <AgreementId>urn:agreementId:</AgreementId>
         </MessageHeader>        
      <RequestReportResponse>
            <Extension>csv</Extension>
            <FileByteArray>xyzFileBytes</FileByteArray>
            <FileName>xyzFileName</FileName>
            <StatusCode>200</StatusCode>
            <StatusDescription>SUCCESS</StatusDescription>
         </RequestReportResponse>
      </RequestReportResponse>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Here is the Liquid map I'm using:

```
{
  "AgreementId": "  {{content.Envelope.Body.RequestReportResponse.MessageHeader.AgreementId}}",
  "FileByteArray": "{{content.Envelope.Body.RequestReportResponse.RequestReportResponse.FileByteArray}}",
  "FileName": "{{content.Envelope.Body.RequestReportResponse.RequestReportResponse.FileName}}",
  "StatusCode": "{{content.Envelope.Body.RequestReportResponse.RequestReportResponse.StatusCode}}",
  "StatusDescription": "{{content.Envelope.Body.RequestReportResponse.RequestReportResponse.StatusDescription}}"
}
```

Expected result:

```
{
  "AgreementId": "urn:agreementId:",
  "FileByteArray": "xyzFileBytes",
  "FileName": "xyzFileName",
  "StatusCode": "200",
  "StatusDescription": "SUCCESS"
}
```

Actual result:

```
{
  "AgreementId": "urn:agreementId:",
  "FileByteArray": "",
  "FileName": "",
  "StatusCode": "",
  "StatusDescription": ""
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems liquid doesn't have good support for the nested same tag name, we can use xslt instead to operate the xml and then transform to json which we want. But it's better for us to improve the format of xml resource to escape nested same tag name.